# SQL except a query result

Tags: sql, search, except

TEST table has **315,729,533** records in total

Using the following query I get One set of result -

```
SELECT count(*)
from test
where Col1 <> '' and Col2='U'

34,270,975
```

I want a Query that can provide me another set of result that gived me Total - last query result (315,729,533-34,270,975 = **281,458,558**)
Records for each Col & Col2 are as follows -

```
Col1    Count
NULL    638
        282221444
~       48
C       34724501
D       37055
F       11
N       3144


Col2    Count
D       3621131
M       1772356
U       311593354
```

Will appreciate inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use:

```
select count(*)
from test
where (Col1 = '' or Col1 is null) or
      (Col2 <> 'U' or Col2 is null);
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, I also have remove some records from the result set. Here is the query that gets me data for records that are FORM and type TIF                                                            `select Col1, Col2, count(*) 
 from Test  
 where Col3 IN ('FORM')  
  AND Col4 = 'TIF'  
group by Col1, Col2  
  

Col1        Col2         Count  
  D  8824  
  M  2038  
  U  713331  `  How can I use it in the main query that you provided so that I can remove these ~700K records from the main resultset,

Comment: @user1596372 . . . Your question here is explicitly asking for a result set, not to remove rows.

Comment: Hello Gordon, I was saying that I got result of 281,458,558 records from your query. Thanks a lot. Now I need to remove records from these 281,458,558 from the result of this query   `select Col2, count(*) from where Col3 IN ('FORM') AND Col4 = 'TIF'   group by Col2`  Result for this query gives me three rows [D (8824 records), M (2038 records), and U (713331 records)].  so, basically I may need to use NOT IN'FORM' and <>'TIF' but its not giving me correct result.  Hope I am able to give more details this time.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user1596372 . . . You have to take `NULL` values into account as well.